# Android Studio App | Firebase Database Reference not working

Tags: java, android, database, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on this bit of code that should reference my Firebase Cloud Database. The idea that if there is no uID in the database, (from a user that has successfully authenticated), that it should send the person to a SetupActivity class. Right now, as this codes stands, it doesn't hit the database and goes straight to my MainActivity. Permissions on the database allows read/write. Anyone have a clue that might be the issue?

```java
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;

    String currentUserID;


    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        //Navigation Drawer
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser == null)
        {
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
        else
        {
            CheckUserExistence();
        }
    }

    private void CheckUserExistence()
    {
        final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id))
                {
                    SendUserToSetupActivity();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void SendUserToSetupActivity()
    {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserToLoginActivity()
    {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment;

        if (id == R.id.nav_leader) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_mypicks) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tribe) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_results) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_chat) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_donate) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            SendUserToLoginActivity();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: What you mean _"goes straight to my MainActivity"_ ? You already at MainActivity, no?

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve, to send users to different activities according to their type?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong,

here `current_user_id` is a uId which is available in Authentication of user

and you are trying to match it with the database key, which is not the same in any way, you must do a comparison with `email` or `phone number` which you are going to authenticate a user.

do something like this,

```
private void CheckUserExistence()
{
    final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();

    UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               User user = dataSnapshot1.getValue(User.class);
               if(user.getEmail().equels(current_user_id))
               {
                  SendUserToSetupActivity();
                  break;
               }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is different on the backend, but when I changed to using the Firebase Realtime Database, the issue was resolved. But it won't work when I use the Firebase Cloud Firestore.